# Converting webpage into pdf

Tags: pdf, web

I have a website which has multiple pages nearly 300 . I want to convert them into pdf . But doing this will take a lot of time . Please tell me some shortcut.

Comment: Are you aware of https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ ?